# postfix-dovecot email sending works with squirrel mail but not with Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email, postfix, dovecot

I have setup an intranet email system using postfix, dovecot and squirrel mail, Which is working fine, I can send and receive mail to all users on the system.  I presume that the issue is in the postfix configuration, because when I configure Thunderbird to send mail I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while sending mail. The mail server responded:  4.1.8 <user@intranetdomain.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found. Please check the message recipient support@intranetdomain.com and try again.
```

Also here is the relevant syslog entries:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from host1.intranetdomain.com [More Information] [192.168.11.1 [More Information] ]: 450 4.1.8 <user@intranetdomain.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<user@intranetdomain.com> to=<support@intranetdomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.0.1 [More Information] ]>
```

I have configured MX records on the DNS server and they respond appropriately when I query them for those MX records, so I do not think that is the issue.  I think that my issue is caused by the default configuration of:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination 
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

Since this is on an internal network and it will not be exposed to the internet as a whole which options can I remove safely?

Comment: so I was able to get thunderbird to send emails by removing reject_unknown_sender_domain and reject_unknown_recipient_domain, but is there a way to resolve this issue without doing that?  Is it a DNS issue?  I do not have forward or reverse records setup for the IPs that are connecting to the mail server, could that be the issue?

Comment: Still looking for any commentary that can be provided on the issue, anyone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```

Don't accept mail from domains that don't exist. [(source)](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists)

---

```
reject_unknown_recipient_domain
```

Reject the request when Postfix is not final destination for the recipient domain, and the RCPT TO domain has 1) no DNS A or MX record or 2) a malformed MX record such as a record with a zero-length MX hostname (Postfix version 2.3 and later) [(source)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions)

---

If you need to change both to make it work, will you have to fake the sender domains in your local DNS or add them to the `/etc/hosts` file on the server. From the explanation, postfix will reject it if it can't look up the domain.

For the second, should you be fine with adding the receiver domain in the servers /etc/hosts file. Explaination: Dovecot use virtual transport, and thus Postfix is, as i have understood it, not considered the final destination and you will need to have proper "path" to the destination. How? Add a DNS A record (to the servers host file) or a proper MX record to your local DNS.

---

For your question: Yes, you can remove safely, but that will turn off the filters refereed above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the line:

```
my_destination = intranetdomain.com, host1.intranetdomain.com, localhost
```

and it will tell postfix that this machine is the responsible for handling e-mails sent to this domain/host.

If this is the only entry/exit point for the internal e-mails you are sending/receiving, it's all you will need.  On the other hand, it's always wise to properly set up your DNS servers, adding MX records for your domain and pointing them to your MTA.

It is advisable to keep `localhost` into the line above so it may handle internal e-mails, sent by other daemons to/from root.

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær, as far as I understood from the question, this is exactly what is missing from the "working configuration" of the OP.  No matter if **canonical or hosted**, postfix has to know about the domain and that it is responsible for it. The way to segregate users and other domains is to use canonical tables, be it virtual or not. But without seeing the actual configuration, it's hard to know what is the OP's intention. ;)

Comment: Wrong, Postfix do gladly take anything on it's queues, regardless of where it is going to deliver it (over smtp, locally or virtually), unless Postfix is told anything else. Here we explicit tell Postfix to restrict on the header fields on its smptd daemon.

Comment: Correction, removing my first comment as it was not related. Then for the follow up: Your answer is missleading as it has nothing to do with the error or the question. `my_destination` is telling what to deliver over local transport and has nothing to do with the header filtering. Also if he is using Dovecot as LDA is `virtual_mailbox_domains` the equivalent of `my_destination` [(source)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær, again as far as I understood, OP is using just one domain, internal and not internet valid. Being so, it doesn't matter if `virtual_mailbox_domains` or `my_destination` is used, as long as `postfix` is told to handle mail sent to that domain. If you don't specify it on any of those transport possibilities, but set your MX pointing to the server, you will end up seeing error messages like "`status=bounced (mail for domain loops back to myself)`". Dovecot will just pick the mail on the mailbox, `postfix` has to know how to put it there... [just one more](http://goo.gl/lRmQgb)

Comment: yes, and if you read his comment can you clearly see he states that it happens when he adds the header filtering and not the lack of destination. The error you are showing above is also none related to the question when assuming all works without the header filtering.

Comment: Again, not seeing his complete conf we are here just ranting about each other solution.  But, removing those header filtering is just letting the server as a open relay, since postfix won't check for validity or even if it **knows** the domain. But, since even the OP isn't giving too much about his own question... it was a nice discussion. ;)

Comment: [I do not understand what part of the manual you do not understand.](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)It clearly states that the open relay is done with `smtpd_relay_restrictions ` and the option `reject_unauth_destination`. It also states if you run with a with a old config or pre 2.10 postfix is it done with `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and the same option `reject_unauth_destination`. We are not discussing the `reject_unauth_destination` part but `reject_unknown_sender_domain` and `reject_unknown_recipient_domain`. So it is no risk of becoming a open relay. Understood? : )

Comment: Yes, it is always good to see the full configuration, but in this case it wasn't needed. I remember myself stumbling with the same questions as a newcomer to postfix. Yes, thanks for the discussion and sorry if I got a bit fired up. : )